# How to find the need of materials from nested estimates in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, product, postgresql-9.2, capacity-planning

Product estimates contain sub-products.
Sub-products can contain also sub-products etc. 
Finally tree leafs contians materials.
Maximum nesting level is 10.

Orders contain also products, sub-products and materials with ordered quantities.
How to find the need of materials required to fullfill the orders?

Products, sub-products and materials are in single table:

```
create table toode (productid char(10) primary key );
```

Estimate table:

```
create table dok (
  dokumnr serial primary key,
  productid char(10) not null references toode
);
```

Sub-products and materials in estimates:

```
create table rid (
  id serial primary key,
  dokumnr int not null references dok,
  itemid char(10) not null references toode,
  quantity  numeric(12,4) -- quantity required to make one product
);
```

Orders:

```
create table orderrows (
  id serial primary key,
  itemid char(10) not null references toode,
  quantity  numeric(12,4)  -- ordered quantity
);
```

Result should be query which return the need of materials and sub-products:

```
itemid char(10) not null references toode,
requiredquantity  numeric(12,4) -- total quantity of items required to make ordered products
```

How to implement this in Postgresql 9.2?
Described fields should remain in those tables. It is possible to add additional
columns and tables if this helps.
Is it possible to make some universal query which works with unilimited nesting level.
Or is it best way to create query which repeats some parts 10 times for maximum nensting level ?

**Update**

estimates

```
product1
  material1  2 pcs
  subproduct2  3 pcs


subproduct2
  material2 4 pcs
```

are described as

```
insert into dok values (1,'product1');
  insert into rid (dokumnr, itemid, quantity) values (1, 'material1', 2);
  insert into rid (dokumnr, itemid, quantity) values (1, 'subproduct2', 3);

insert into dok values (2,'subproduct2');
  insert into rid (dokumnr, itemid, quantity) values (2, 'material2', 4);
```

If 10 pieces of product1 are ordered this is described as:

```
insert into orderrows (itemid, quantity ) values ('product1', 10);
```

Result should be:

```
material1  20 
material2  120
```

material1 quantity is calculated as 10*2.

material2 quantity is calculated as 10*3*4

**Update 2**

Joachim answer gives incorrect result on multi level estimates when last level contains more that one row. Last join `LEFT JOIN rid rid2 ON rid2.dokumnr = dok2.dokumnr` returns multiple rows and result table is duplicated.

Testcase http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/e5c11/1/0  :

```
create table toode (productid char(15) primary key );

create table dok (
  dokumnr serial primary key,
  productid char(15) not null references toode
);

create table rid (
  id serial primary key,
  dokumnr int not null references dok,
  itemid char(15) not null references toode,
  quantity  numeric(12,4) -- quantity required to make one product
);

create table orderrows (
  id serial primary key,
  itemid char(15) not null references toode,
  quantity  numeric(12,4)  -- ordered quantity
);

INSERT INTO toode VALUES ('product1'),('material1'),('subproduct2'), ('material2'), ('material3');
insert into dok values (1,'product1');
insert into dok values (2,'subproduct2');

insert into rid (dokumnr, itemid, quantity) values (1, 'material1', 1);
insert into rid (dokumnr, itemid, quantity) values (1, 'subproduct2', 1);
insert into rid (dokumnr, itemid, quantity) values (2, 'material2', 1);
insert into rid (dokumnr, itemid, quantity) values (2, 'material3', 1);

insert into orderrows (itemid, quantity ) values ('product1', 1);
```

Expected:

Every quantity is 1 so result quantity must be 1 for every material.

Observed:

Material2 and matererial3 rows are  duplicated.

How to fix this ? Query should determine leaf nodes itself. Leaf nodes are not marked specially in data.

Comment: could you please put some test data with desired output?

Comment: @Roman Pekar : I updated question with sample data and result

Comment: Sounds like you want to look at 'WITH RECURSIVE' (see here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html). I don't have access to a postgres system at the moment to actually build/test an example query.

Comment: @SpaceDog: Thank you. I will try to understand WITH RECURSIVE , never used it. This can probably done by joining estimate table withs orderrows 10 times and using lot of COALESCE and CASE WHEN Not sure is this best way, nesting level is hard coded and query is long. You can use Sql Fiddle to create query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it using a recursive query;

```
WITH RECURSIVE t(itemid,qty) AS (
  SELECT itemid,quantity,false isleaf FROM orderrows
  UNION ALL
  SELECT rid.itemid,(rid.quantity*t.qty)::NUMERIC(12,4),
         dok2.productid IS NULL
  FROM t 
  JOIN dok ON dok.productid=t.itemid
  JOIN rid ON rid.dokumnr=dok.dokumnr
  LEFT JOIN dok dok2 ON dok2.productid=rid.itemid
)
SELECT itemid, SUM(qty) FROM t WHERE isleaf GROUP BY itemid
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/c9bb5/2).

Comment: +1 yes, it's better to test if it's leaf than just assume that name like 'material', but I think OP should have more efficient way

Comment: Thank you very much. Excellent. How to add column to result table which contains comma-separated list of products for which this row material is used. Is it possible to use string_add or some array function for this ?

Comment: @Andrus Check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/451aa/1 and see if it's what you're looking for.

Comment: @Joachim. Thank you. This works. However your answer is incorrect, it produces wrong results, rows are duplicated. I updated question and unmarked answer. How to fix this ?

Comment: @Andrus Updated the answer and sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Try this query:

```
;with recursive cte as (
    select r.itemid, r.quantity * o.quantity as quantity, false as is_material
    from orderrows as o
        inner join dok as d on d.productid = o.itemid
        inner join rid as r on r.dokumnr = d.dokumnr

    union

    select r.itemid, r.quantity * o.quantity as quantity, itemid like 'material%'
    from cte as o
        inner join dok as d on d.productid = o.itemid
        inner join rid as r on r.dokumnr = d.dokumnr
)
select * from cte as c
where c.itemid not in (select t.productid from dok as t);
```

here's [**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/e08f2/8) example to test it. Here I'm assuming that your define materials as products which name starts with 'material', but I think that you should have an attribute `is_material` or something like that in your DB, so you could change this condition.

**update** - test case [**sql fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/e5c11/9)

Comment: itemids of material can be any codes. They do not start with material. Query should determine leaf nodes itself, data does not have such property. Joachim leaf node determination was wrong. I updated queston and provided testcase. How to fix this?

Comment: thank you. This may work, I upvoted it some days ago. However I marked Joahchim answer as answer since he provided general solution first and this allows also to get list of materials which I asked in this answer comment and for which Joachim provides solution in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/451aa/1

Comment: no prob, Joahchim indeed provided general solution first, thanks fo upvoting